# Should I Reuse StreamObservers in gRPC Java?

Tags: grpc

I'm new to gRPC and writing an application in which 8 clients send 50k asynchronous requests per second to a gRPC server. I know that I should reuse the channel for each client, but how about the StreamObserver? Now I create a new StreamObserver every time a client issues a request. Will this be a bottleneck? Any reply would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there no need to create StreamObserver for every request. Just send request by `StreamObserver#onNext`, after send all request, you can close it.

```
        StreamObserver<HelloMessage> requestObserver = stub.sayHello(streamObserver);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            HelloMessage message = HelloMessage.newBuilder()
                                               .setMessage(i + " Server Stream")
                                               .build();

            requestObserver.onNext(message);
        }
        requestObserver.onCompleted();
```